# Find the cartesian equation from the given parametric equations

Tags: calculus, parametric

I'm tasked with converting these parametric equations into one cartesian equation.
$$ x = a*sin(t) $$
$$ y = b*cos(t) $$

So I begin with my reasoning, which is potentially 100% wrong.

I want to basically solve for `t` and then substitute. 
*assuming that is a valid thing to do.*

$$ \frac{x}{a}=sin(t) $$
$$ arcsin(\frac{x}{a})=t $$
$$ y = b*cos(arcsin((\frac{x}{a})) $$

but now what? is this even acceptable? I'm new to parametric equations and despite searching extensively for answers to this and similar situations I'm having a terrible time making sense of this type of math.
Help me math.stackexchange, you're my only hope...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simpler and more elegant way of forming the cartesian equation.
$$\begin{align}
bx&=ba\sin(t)\\
ay&=ab\cos(t)
\end{align}$$
Squaring we get
$$\begin{align}
(bx)^2&=(ba\sin(t))^2\\
(ay)^2&=(ab\cos(t))^2
\end{align}$$
Add the two equations we get
$$\begin{align}
(bx)^2+(ay)^2&=(ba\sin(t))^2+(ab\cos(t))^2\\
&=(ab)^2(\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t))\\
&=(ab)^2
\end{align}$$
Simplifying by dividing both side by $(ab)^2$.
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Assuming $a\neq 0 , b\neq 0\implies \dfrac x a = \sin t \text { and } \dfrac y b = \cos t$.

There is a fundamental equation involving just $\sin t$ and $\cos t$. Apply it and you get the equation in $x,y$ - coordinates.

Comment: $$ cos^2(t)+sin^2(t)=1 $$

Comment: Exactly! That's the fundamental equation!